# Secure file system utility functions

Tags: performance, algorithm, c, file, portability

For [Khronos](https://github.com/syb0rg/Khronos), I've had to develop these utility functions to help me deal with storing the `.wav` files.  However, they could also be used in a variety of applications.

*A description of what the three functions do are given in the header documentation comments.*

---

**util.h**:

```
#ifndef UTIL_H
#define UTIL_H

/**
 * @return the temporary file directory for your system
 */
const char* getTmpDir(void);

/**
 * Generates a unique temporary filename given the fileroot, creates and opens the file
 * @return file descriptor to the open file
 */
int createSafeFileDescriptor(const char* fileRoot);

/**
 * Fetches the file path given the file descriptor
 * @return file path
 */
const char* getPathFromDescriptor(int fd);

#endif // UTIL_H
```

**util.c**:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#ifndef _WIN32
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#endif

#include "util.h"

const char* getTmpDir(void)
{
    char *tmpdir = NULL;
    if ((tmpdir = getenv("TEMP"))) return tmpdir;
    else if ((tmpdir = getenv("TMP"))) return tmpdir;
    else if ((tmpdir = getenv("TMPDIR"))) return tmpdir;
    else return "/tmp/";
}

int createSafeFileDescriptor(const char* fileRoot)
{
    // Creates temporary file safely
    char flacFile[FILENAME_MAX] = "";
    snprintf(flacFile, FILENAME_MAX, "%sXXXXXX.wav", fileRoot);

    // the 5 is for the length of the suffix ".wav"
    return mkstemps(flacFile, 4);
}

const char* getPathFromDescriptor(int fd)
{
    char *filename = malloc(FILENAME_MAX);
#ifdef _WIN32
    intptr_t file = _get_osfhandle(fd);
    intptr_t fileMap = CreateFileMapping(file, NULL, PAGE_READONLY, 0, 1, NULL);

    if (hFileMap)
    {
        void* pMem = MapViewOfFile(hFileMap, FILE_MAP_READ, 0, 0, 1);
        if (pMem)
        {
            if (GetMappedFileName(GetCurrentProcess(), pMem, filename, FILENAME_MAX)) return filename;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
#endif

#ifdef __APPLE__
    if (fcntl(fd, F_GETPATH, filename) != -1) return filename;
    return NULL;
#endif

#ifdef __unix__
    char proclnk[PATH_MAX] = {0};
    ssize_t r = -1;
    snprintf(proclnk, sizeof(proclnk), "/proc/self/fd/%d", fd);
    if ((r = readlink(proclnk, filename, FILENAME_MAX)) < 0) return NULL;
    filename[r] = '\0';
    return filename;
#endif
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Good set of code.

**Observations**

1. `#ifdef` structure lacks uniqueness and detection if none are true.  Suggest `#elif`

   ```
   #ifdef _WIN32
   #elif __APPLE__
   #elif __unix__
   #else
   #error Error Message
   #endif
   ```
2. Rather than a differing `#if` structure in the `.c` file, suggest a matching one as in #1

   ```
   //#ifndef _WIN32
   //#endif
   #ifdef _WIN32
   #elif __APPLE__
   ...
   ```
3. Memory leak.  Should `free(filename)` before returning `NULL`.

   ```
   if ((r = readlink(proclnk, filename, FILENAME_MAX)) < 0) return NULL;
   ```
4. Name-space.  Prefer some naming convention that ties these 3 functions to 
   their `.h` file.  Maybe `wavutil`?

   ```
   wavutil.h
   wavutil_getTmpDir();
   wavutil_createSafeFileDescriptor()
   wavutil_getPathFromDescriptor();
   ```
5. Since function *allocates* data, make that clear in the function declaration.  Also document candidate error returns

   ```
   * ALLOCATES the file path given the file descriptor
   * Returns NULL on ...
   ...
   const char* getPathFromDescriptor(int fd);
   ```
6. Suggest error return of `NULL` instead.  Hoping `"/tmp/"` exists after failing 3 environment variables it a questionable fix.  At least `"./"` is sure to exist.  Also the environment variable might not end with `/`.  May need to check that.

   ```
   // else return "/tmp/";
   else return NULL;
   // or 
   else return "./";
   ```
7. `snprintf()` is good to prevent overruns, yet if it fails, do not proceed with a runt string.

   ```
   int len = snprintf(proclnk, sizeof(proclnk), "/proc/self/fd/%d", fd);
   if (len < 0 || len >= sizeof(proclnk)) Handle_Error();
   if ((r = readlink(proclnk, filename, FILENAME_MAX)) < 0) return NULL;
   ```

**Minor**

1. Comment inconsistent with code 5 vs. 4?  Could avoid magic number 4.

   ```
      // // the 5 is for the length of the suffix ".wav"
      // return mkstemps(flacFile, 4);

      char ext[] = ".wav";
      snprintf(flacFile, FILENAME_MAX, "%sXXXXXX%s", fileRoot, ext);
      return mkstemps(flacFile, sizeof ext - 1);
   ```
2. Prefer right-sizing allocations that start off large.

   ```
      char *filename = malloc(FILENAME_MAX);
      ...
      char *p = realloc(filename, strlen(filename) + 1);
      return p ? p : filename;
   ```
3. Curious style change.  Why `sizeof()` in 2nd line, yet `FILENAME_MAX` instead of `sizeof(flacFile)`.  Suggest the latter.  Further, not a fan of `xxx_MAX` when `xxx_SIZE` is meant.  `MAX` to me means the maximum number so characters - which is 1 less than *size*.

   ```
   char proclnk[PATH_MAX] = {0};
   snprintf(proclnk, sizeof(proclnk), "/proc/self/fd/%d", fd);

   char flacFile[FILENAME_MAX] = "";
   snprintf(flacFile, FILENAME_MAX, "%sXXXXXX.wav", fileRoot);
   ```